# Does JavaScript/jQuery always have the latest element or version of that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a userscript that grabs an element with something like:

```
var theElement = $('div.someClass:last');
```

To grab the last element in the class `.someClass` so I can parse it.

This is where my question comes in.  There is another script on this page dynamically adding a new `<div class="someClass">` every once in a while.  I want to always have the last element on the page with a class of `.someClass` selected.

Will Javascript/jQuery always have the latest element or will I have to manually "refresh" it?

Comment: The jQuery function gets the elements from the DOM, and the variable holds those elements, so you'll need to update the variable to reflect any changes done in the DOM structure after the variable was last updated.

Comment: In short, no. You'll have to re-create your jQuery element periodically.

Comment: jQuery collections are not live.

Comment: It's pretty easy to emulate if you use live node lists `var theElement = $(liveNodeList[liveNodeList.length - 1]);`. As the result `theElement` is always up to date.

Comment: @dfsq Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: `wheresrhys` added the similar answer so I would accept that one :)

Comment: they appear to be live in [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/Pv5sk/1/)? Is that because the value is being set via jQuery?

Comment: @jbabey I don't think that counts because, if I know how a timer works, your function will get called every second, so the value gets refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sushanth's answer is correct, but according to [this article](http://darcyclarke.me/development/live-vs-static-node-lists/) you could use

```
var theElements = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
```

and then reliably use

```
var theElement = $(theElements[theElements.length - 1]); // wrapping in $() is optional
```

which is worth doing as $(selector) is quite an expensive operation to perform.

*edit* - only for ie9 and above though http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is evaluated and the result is returned.  If you want to do what you're asking, you'll have to re-evaluate that selector.

Comment: Go figure, that's what I thought.  Kinda a dumb question I know.

Answer (score 4):

**Nope .. It will not be automatically refreshed.**

Every single time you modify something directly on the selector it is a good idea to cache it again.

The selector you wish is not a [**live Node list.**](http://darcyclarke.me/development/live-vs-static-node-lists/)

In such cases if there seem to any changes in the selector I prefer not to cache at all in the first case.

So that I can directly use the **selector and not the cached one.**